# Global sections of canonical line bundle on projective curve with everywhere vanishing derivative

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, divisors, projective-varieties, derivations

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of positive characteristic $p$, $C$ be a curve (projective, non-singular, connected) of genus $g\geq 2$ over $k$ and $\omega \in H^0(C, \Omega_C)$ be a regular differential on $C$ with associated canonical divisor $ Z = \operatorname{div} \omega = n_1 P_1+ \cdots + n_l P_l$.

I am wondering how many elements of $H^0(C, \mathscr O_C(Z))$ have an everywhere vanishing derivative. To put it differently, if $k(C)$ denotes the function field of $C$, I would like know the dimension of $H^0(C, \mathscr O_C(Z)) \cap k(C)^p$. Clearly this vector space is at least one dimensional (containg $k$) and it coincides with $k$ if $n_i < p$ for all $i$. But I have no idea what happens in the case $n_i \geq p$ for some $i$. It would already be helpful to have an example where the vector space contains a non-constant function.

To give some context: The dimension $d$ of the vector space $H^0(C, \mathscr O_C(Z)) \cap k(C)^p$ is related to the dimension of the tangent space of the stratum of the Hodge bundle at the point $(C,\omega)$. Indeed, the dimension of said tangent space is $2g-2+l+d$.

Comment: You should first explain how you construct the intersection $H^0(C, \mathscr O_C(Z)) \cap k(C)^p$: The global sections of a line bundle do not not naturally form a subspace of the function field.

Comment: What I meant is that $H^0(C, \mathscr O_C(Z)) = \{f \in k(C) \mid \operatorname{div}(f) + Z \geq 0\} \subseteq k(C)$. Would it be more clear if I use the symbol $\mathcal L(Z)$?

Comment: This might be nitpicking, but perhaps you should not denote the number of points in $Z$ by the same letter ($k$) as the base field...

Comment: Also, do I understand it correctly that what you are asking is this: fix a canonical divisor $Z$, and then for any effective canonical divisor $Z'$ take the rational function, say $f_{Z'}$, whose principal divisor is $Z'-Z$. Then your question is "what is the dimension of the space of those $f_{Z'}$ that are in $K(C)^p$?" (where $K(C)$ is the function field of $C$).

Comment: @SándorKovács Thanks for the info, I fixed the notation for the number of zeros. As for the second comment: The first canonical divisor $Z$ should also be effective. Then this would indeed be a reformulation of my question.